# error using auto: does not name a type, c++ version of numpy's arange

Tags: c++, templates, vector, auto, typename

Looking for code to implement `numpy`'s `arange` function in c++, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217377/2623899).

I placed the following code in a file `test_arange_c.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> arange(T start, T stop, T step = 1)
{
  std::vector<T> values;
  for (T value = start; value < stop; value += step)
    values.push_back(value);
  return values;
}

int main()
{
  double dt;
  dt = 0.5;
  auto t_array = arange<double>(0, 40, dt);
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
$ c++ test_arange_c.cpp -o test_arange_c.out
test_arange_c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_arange_c.cpp:14:8: error: ‘t_array’ does not name a type
   auto t_array = arange<double>(0, 40, dt);
```

Without doubt, I've made a mistake that will be obvious to seasoned c++ users.  But, after searching Google for a while, I haven't come up with what it is.

Comment: It looks like you haven't enabled C++11 support, or your compiler doesn't have it.

Comment: @Brian is there an easy way to check for this?  would reporting my compiler version tell you whether that's the case?

Comment: You can check whether C++11 is enabled for a given compilation using the `__cplusplus` macro. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047971/how-do-i-check-for-c11-support

Comment: If you want to know whether your compiler implements C++11 at all, you should consult the documentation.

Comment: @Brian what keyword is it exactly that requires C++11 here?  (i want to change the question title so people who get this error with this keyword in the future have an easier time finding the solution.)

Comment: You need C++11 for your use of `auto`. Before C++11, `auto` meant "this is an automatic variable" and would have to be followed by a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brian suggested, I had not enabled `C++11` support.

```
$ c++ --version
c++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This fails:

```
$ c++ test_arange_c.cpp -o test_arange_c.out
test_arange_c.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_arange_c.cpp:16:8: error: ‘t_array’ does not name a type
   auto t_array = arange<double>(0, 40, dt);
        ^
```

This works:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 test_arange_c.cpp -o test_arange_c.out
$
```